# When adding a table and a row as html elements, jQuery dismisses the content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have the following code:

```
htmlElement = $('<' + chosenTag + '>' + insideHTML + '</' + chosenTag + '>');
$('#container').append(htmlElement);
```

If `htmlElement` and `chosenTag` are both equal to `div`, then after execution of this code a `div` element is created within container. Same goes with other tags: `h1-h6, ul, span, ol, li, etc...`

But for some reason, if the tag is `table` or `tr` the code doesn't work properly. If `htmlElement` and `chosenTag` are both equal to `table` (or `tr`), then `alert(htmlElement.html());` returns `undefined`.

When this element is appended to the container, it is created without `insideHTML` (html, that is between the tags), yet this `insideHTML` for some reason is placed before this new element. So it is like:

```
<div id="container">
    table
    <table></table>
</div>
```

**WHY** is this happening and how to fix that?

Comment: Make sure you're creating valid HTML. The children of `<table>` can only be certain elements like `<tr>` and `<tbody>`. And the children of `<tr>` can only be `<td>` or `<th>`. If you try something else, they'll be ignored.

Comment: E.g. `<table>table</table>` is not valid, it has to be `<table><tr><td>table</td></tr></table>`

Comment: But that would be a problem with valid html, why jQuery bugs me about that? I mean, how jQuery cares, about such html details?

Comment: It's creating DOM nodes using the browser's built-in HTML parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of [`jQuery( html [, ownerDocument ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery2):

> If the HTML is more complex than a single tag without attributes, ..., the actual creation of the elements is handled by the browser's `.innerHTML` mechanism. In most cases, jQuery creates a new `<div>` element and sets the `innerHTML` property of the element to the HTML snippet that was passed in.
>   ...
>   To ensure cross-platform compatibility, the snippet must be well-formed.

You're trying to put contents into the `<table>` and `<tr>` that aren't valid. A `<table>` can't contain a text node as a direct child, it must be enclosed in a `<tr>` and `<td>/<th>`.